# I have Samba 3.x running on a server and i want to change passwords

Tags: script, samba

So I have a Samba 3.x (don't know exactly) running on a server and what i want is to write a script or whatever, whichcan handle a file and change the user's password to a new one (which are in the given file).

Basically: 
Server
     user old password, 
     *script run, and uses a given file*
     user newpassword

What's in the file? In the given file there will be user newpassword

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `smbpasswd` as usual.

```
while read -r the_user new_password; do
    (echo "$new_password";
     echo "$new_password") | smbpasswd "$the_user"
done < file.txt
```